# add-migration can not read the connection string from the file appsettings.json because of the path to appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp-net-core-spa-services

Tools: VS2017, ASP.NET Core 2, Entity Framework Core 2, ASP.NET Core JavaScript Services

I am using the following BuildWebHost methode:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName))
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseNLog()
    .Build();
```

For loading the connection string I have the following code in ConfigureServices (startup.cs):

```
Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsAction = options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RecipeDatabase")); 
services.AddDbContext<RecipeContext>(optionsAction);
```

With the above configuration the app runs without problems in debug mode and as windows service (after publishing).

But if I run add-migration the tool is not able to load the connection string from appsettings.json:

[image]

If I comment the following line like so

```
//.UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName))
```

add-migration runs without problems but the app running as "Windows Service" not because it will not find the appsettings.json file.

How can I modify the configuration so that it is not necessary to comment the above line anymore?

Thank you.

Michael

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to override OnConfiguring method in your DbContext. Here is an example I'm using. It will work whenever you are using command line or windows service:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        return;
    }

    string pathToContentRoot = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string json = Path.Combine(pathToContentRoot, "appsettings.json");

    if (!File.Exists(json))
    {
        string pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
    }

    IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(pathToContentRoot)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

    IConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("RecipeDatabase"));

    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be promising! I will check it out asap. Thank you.

Comment: OK, you pointed me in the right direction, so your answer helped me to solve the problem.
Finally I have implemented the interface "IDesignTimeDbContextFactory" and renamed "BuildWebHost" to "BuildHost" because of the following blog post: https://wildermuth.com/2018/01/10/Re-thinking-Running-Migrations-and-Seeding-in-ASP-NET-Core-2-0.
Add-Migration will use "IDesignTimeDbContextFactory" if it is implemented. But by convention it will check first for "BuildWebHost" and will never execute "IDesignTimeDbContextFactory" if it finds it. This will be fixed by renaming "BuildWebHost".

Comment: I use it, and it worked ! thanks !  if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        return;
    }

Answer (score 2):

In development environment, it's preferred to use "User Secrets" for storing configuration rather than appsettings.json. You get User Secrets on Solution Explorer > Project's Context Menu > Manage User Secrets.

User Secrets stores configuration in current user's romaing profile directory for example: C:\users\john\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets\ProjectName012822aasd\secrets.json

While User Secrets option is meant only for development environment, for production you need to rely on other configuration management for example: Azure App Service's App Config.

Here's Microsoft's documentation on [User Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets)

Answer (score 0):

I'm including secrets.json in Program.cs. This file is stored outside of repository and is added in project as link. After that it's content is accesible for example as `Configuration["SectionName:SectionLine"]`. The `SetBasePath` code line fixes errors when accessing this file when creating migrations etc..

```
  public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    var basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Launched program with base at {basePath}");
                    config.SetBasePath(basePath);
                    config.AddJsonFile("secrets.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                    config.AddJsonFile($"secrets.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
#if DEV_DB
                    config.AddJsonFile($"secrets.LocalDb.json", optional: true);
#endif
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```